# how to create custom report with JShint

Tags: node.js, jshint

Create own report jshint

JSHint and outputs instead of console i want separate report in text file generate

suggest complete code

how to compile the complete report

Answer (score 0):

Jshint can be used as a nodejs module so you can write a script that will do anything you need with jshint output.